# JSON.stringify in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Why when I use JSON.stringify in node.js on data from database request I get objects with the data itself, and if I use console.log I get a lot of additional parameters like dataValues, _previousDataValues, _modelOptions....
I use sequelize.js

console.log(JSON.stringify(data,'',2))

```
{
  id:1
}
```

console.log(data)

```
Kindergarten_data {
  dataValues:
    { id: 1}
 _changed: {},
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: true,
     underscored: false,
     underscoredAll: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: null,
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: [],
     indexes: [],...
```

Comment: And what's the problem? You're using `sequelize`, it returns you models, e.g. objects with data, methods, hooks etc.

Comment: I want to know why JSON.stringify shows only data values from database . Why not full object? Why JSON.stringify ignore _previousDataValues, _modelOptions....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` returns JSON-safe string representation of its input(eg JS object). It will strip off all properties/fields which doesn't have an equivalent JSON representation.
Whereas `console.log()` outputs the JS object as it is to the console.

Comment: You answer is incomplete. For example, `_modelOptions` (from example) does have JSON representation. See answer from @tevemodar

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.stringify()` has a [protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) which it follows:

> JSON.stringify() converts a value to JSON notation representing it:
>
> - If the value has a `toJSON()` method, it's responsible to define what data will be serialized.
> - `Boolean`, `Number`, and `String` objects are converted to the corresponding primitive values during stringification, in accord with the traditional conversion semantics.
> - [...]

It is pretty obvious that your stringified stuff simply does not follow what you see with `console.log()`, since you would have to see `{ dataValues: {id: 1} ...`, but you see `{id: 1}` instead. So it is not about some mystical "JSON-representability" other answers may suggest, but `sequelize.js` simply provides `toJSON()` method, and thus it JSON-exports only your data, not the entire infrastructure.

The method is here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model.js#L4226

> ```
> toJSON() {
>   return _.cloneDeep(
>     this.get({
>       plain: true
>     })
>   );
> }
> ```

The `get()` it refers is here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model.js#L3313

> ```
> get(key, options) {
>   if (options === undefined && typeof key === 'object') {
>     options = key;
>     key = undefined;
>   }
>
>   [...]
>
>   if (key) {
>     [...]
>   }
>
>   return this.dataValues;
> }
> ```

[`cloneDeep()`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L126) just makes a copy of the thing, it does not matter here.
What matters is the `return this.dataValues;` above. That is the line which strips the object you see in the console, and results in serializing only its `dataValues` field.

Small-scale demo:

```js
var data1={
  dataValues:{id:1},
  somethingElse:[1,2,3],
  _stuff:{a:'b'}
};

var data2={
  dataValues:{id:1},
  somethingElse:[1,2,3],
  _stuff:{a:'b'},
  toJSON:function(){return this.dataValues;}
};

console.log("data1:",JSON.stringify(data1));
console.log("data2:",JSON.stringify(data2));
```